# cannot create the proper view to display product from a selected category url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I want to display a list of product by a categorie.
First time I get on the site, I show up a list of category URL.  If you click on a URL, I will like
to get all products related to this category.
My HomeController was based on the Category when I build it.
When I am doing the view for the Browse, I took the Categorie for the model.  I am not sure if it is the good one.   I also tried to use the Product by it was not working either.
Can someone explain me what should be done do generate the proper solution?
Thanks

Currently I got this error: 
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MVCWebStore.Models.Produit]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MVCWebStore.Models.Categorie'.

Here is the HomeController.cs  (build base on the Produit)

```
 namespace MVCWebStore.Controllers
 {
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
      private MVCWebStoreDdEntities1 db = new MVCWebStoreDdEntities1();

      public ActionResult Browse(int id = 0)
      {
        var categorieProduitToEdit = (from c in db.Produits where c.IdCategorie == id select c);

        if (categorieProduitToEdit == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

          return View(categorieProduitToEdit.ToList());
    }
```

Here is the Browse.cshtml

```
 @model MVCWebStore.Models.Categorie

 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Browse";
 }

 <ul>
     @foreach (var produit in Model.Produits)
     {
        <li>
             @produit.Description
        </li>
     }
 </ul>
```

Produit.cs

```
 namespace MVCWebStore.Models
 {
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Produit
    {
         public Produit()
         {
             this.ItemPaniers = new HashSet<ItemPanier>();
         }

         public int IdProduit { get; set; }
         public int IdCategorie { get; set; }
         public string NomProduit { get; set; }
         public string Description { get; set; }
         public double Prix { get; set; }
         public int Quantite { get; set; }

         public virtual Categorie Categorie { get; set; }
         public virtual ICollection<ItemPanier> ItemPaniers { get; set; }
     }
  }
```

Categorie.cs

```
 namespace MVCWebStore.Models
 {
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;

     public partial class Categorie
     {
         public Categorie()
         {
             this.Produits = new HashSet<Produit>();
         }

         public int IdCategorie { get; set; }
         public string NomCategorie { get; set; }

         public virtual ICollection<Produit> Produits { get; set; }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you what your view is expecting. At the moment it is expecting a single item, but you are passing a collection of items.

pass it a Categorie model with the collection of produits in the model

```
public class HomeController : Controller
```

{
      private MVCWebStoreDdEntities1 db = new MVCWebStoreDdEntities1();

```
  public ActionResult Browse(int id = 0)
  {

  //GET THE CATEGORIE
  var Categorie = //GET THE CATEGORIE FROM THE DATABASE


    var categorieProduitToEdit = (from c in db.Produits where c.IdCategorie == id select c);

    if (categorieProduitToEdit == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    //BUILD THE MODEL
   Categorie.produits = categorieProduitToEdit.ToList();

      return View(Categorie);
}
```

Comment: I did what you said @model ICollection <MVCWebStore.Models.Categorie>  but got another error.  The point here is to be on the product table and display the choosen category. I am not sure it should be Categorie  should it be Produit insted ?@model ICollection <MVCWebStore.Models.Categorie>

Comment: here is the error message CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<MVCWebStore.Models.Categorie>' does not contain a definition for 'Produits' and no extension method 'Produits' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<MVCWebStore.Models.Categorie>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Ok I fixed the problem.  My view was not using the Scaffold template List and I changed the  @Model ...Models.Produits> instead of Categorie.  It works NOW !!!!  thanks a lot.

Comment: I am not sure your answer is correct.  I deleted the Browse view and regenerate it base on Produit and I choose the Scaffold template LIST.  In the model I put ICollection like you said.  That's it

Comment: both will work. if you don't need your categorie information in the view then just use the icollection of products. if you need information about the categorie then pass in the categorie with the collection of products attached.